# Unicode support for libtecla

Tags: c++, c, linux

In our CLI(Linux) application,we are using Libtecla library to handle input/output operations. When we are trying to enable Unicode support in CLI application,the Unicode characters are not showing in CLI(empty characters).These are the below steps are followed to access the unicode characters,

- Enabled LANG=en_US.UTF-8 format in terminal
- Added setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "") in our code(C Programming)

  But still I am getting the same result.
  I need to read user input in any languages, i.e., any utf-8 characters.
  I really appreciated if anyone help this above issue.

Comment: can you show the output of `locale -a`?

Comment: I don't believe that libtecla supports multibyte encodings (or wide strings), so you probably should find a different input library.

Comment: Murali2:~# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
POSIX

Comment: Murali2:~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8